# WatchKit: call popToRootController after user tap on back (cancel) upper-left corner button

Tags: ios, watchkit, back-button, back, wkinterfacecontroller

I have 3 WKInterfaceController (A,B,C) and  hierarchical navigation. So user goes: A->B->C.

Then user can tap the upper-left corner of the screen or performs a left-edge swipe and by default he will go C->B->A.

But I want to skip B and use popToRootController - so I need C -> A.

popToRootController in didDeactivate does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually thats not possible currently in WatchOS 1.0, as default back button have its own functionality. Lets hope watchOS 2 comes up with some changes in navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made intermediate empty screen B2 for fast redirecting to C. So user goes A->B->B2->C.
Then he goes back C->B2 and on B2 I use popToRootController and he goes to A.
Not great workaround but it works